# Normalize a Numpy array of 2D vector by a Pandas column of norms

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Numpy array of 2D coordinates :

```py
uv = np.array([[u_1, v_1],
               [u_2, v_2],
               [u_3, v_3]])
```

I need to normalize it by a vector containing a list of norms for each vector stored as a Pandas Series:

```py
L = pd.Series([L_1, L_2, L_3])
```

Expected result:

```py
uv = np.array([[u_1 / L_1, v_1 / L_1],
               [u_2 / L_2, v_2 / L_2],
               [u_3 / L_3, v_3 / L_3]])
```

So, of course I can do it by slicing the vector:

```py
uv[:,0] /= L
uv[:,1] /= L
```

But knowing Numpy, there should be a more efficient way to do it in one line and one loop over the data. What is it ?

`np.multiply()` does not have an axis argument and complains : `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2816,2) (2816,)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If both arrays are in numpy, you just need to Transpose it:

```
(uv.T/L).T
```

In the case of the question, as `L` is a Series, then:

```
(uv.T/L.to_numpy()).T
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried. Result : `ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (2816)`

Comment: I just understood why… `L` is stored as a `pandas.Dataframe` column, and it is not directly converted to `numpy.array` when doing matrices operations. So, using `L.to_numpy()` yields the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution is :

```py
(uv.T / L.to_numpy()).T
```

It seems `pandas.Series` support scalar operations but need to be cast as explicit `np.array` to enable vector/matrices operations.